# How to achieve this western sound on guitar?

Tags: effects, guitar

I'm trying to achieve an especific sound on my guitar, and I don't know how to do it. The sound feels like those Wild West themes. I don't know if it's a banjo, or a guitar effect actually, so any tips help.

The sound I'm talking about are not the chords. It does the same thing that the bass do in the beginning of the song.

I'm not using real amps yet cause I don't have one, but I use Amplitube to emulate my guitar amps, so what would be the best way to emulate that sound?

This is the song *I wanna be yours* by *Arctic Monkeys*:

Answer (score 2):

This sound can be achieved with a `spring reverb` and a `short delay` (< 100ms). Delay before the reverb.

Along with this western sound in general you often also hear `tremolo` and `chorus` effects. Here, though, it is very subtle  - if there at all. Try a gentle chorus.

Also (depending on your guitar model): try switching to some of the `center pick-up` positions.

EDIT: And like discussed below it is also very much in the playing itself: palm muted "firmly picked" notes.

Comment: he's not talking about the chords..

Comment: @frcake what do you mean? I'm not talking about chords either..

Comment: but don't you hear is a picked guitar with palm muting? at the bridge position (fender ) neck position(gibson) . it's a classic thechnique..

Comment: @frcake He is asking about the sound, the effects (and pickup setting) is about the sound. Not sure why you would oppose to that.. what do you think the answer should be about then?

Comment: this is a sound depending 100% on the attack , the DS is the reverb, but the actual sound needs the palm mute, cause it needs to be very dampened, the best way would be to go with either of the 2 setups i mentioned (guitar wise and pickup wise), Also chorus would kinda kill the sound, i mean if you have an amp with great clean headroom like a twin reverb and a nice reverb unit (TR has both ) you can reproduce this sound 100%. So you palm mute and either you pick the string with your fingers and leave it so it hits the fret a bit

Comment: or you pick the string with the pick close to the palm mute (bridge) so you get a bit more quack which is actually the attack, you can't let the guitar resonate by hitting an open string cause it will ruin the dampened-empty attack effect.

Comment: You're both right. It's palm muted. There's a slapback delay. And there's reverb. There may also be some subtle tremolo or chorus. I can't agree with the reductive view of Gibson and Fender guitar sounds, though. Both companies make too wide a variety of guitars to say "Fender sounds like this, Gibson sounds like that".

Comment: it was just a reference (about the guitars) of course there are numerous setups but those 2 are kind of standard. i do agree on the slapback delay and tremolo (Very subtle one) don't know about the chorus since there's nothing to actually detune here but ok, but the palm thing is crucial.that's all.